# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to create a Gradle project to register Eureka services. Main method configuration:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I use this gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server', version: '3.0.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But when I compile the project I get this error:

```
2021-05-03 01:30:21.661  INFO 23396 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=de56758b-78fd-328a-9faf-0cacba840b49
2021-05-03 01:30:22.798  INFO 23396 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-03 01:30:22.835  INFO 23396 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-03 01:30:22.837  INFO 23396 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-03 01:30:23.045 ERROR 23396 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.skyshop.server.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5089) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1355) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        ... 48 common frames omitted

2021-05-03 01:30:23.049 ERROR 23396 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
        at org.skyshop.server.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5089) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1355) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
        ... 48 common frames omitted

2021-05-03 01:30:23.057  INFO 23396 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-05-03 01:30:23.070  WARN 23396 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-05-03 01:30:23.106  INFO 23396 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-03 01:30:23.207 ERROR 23396 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1355)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/skyshop-registry/build/libs/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/skyshop-registry/build/libs/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/skyshop-registry/build/libs/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: In stacktrace, you have a message: `Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext` check dependencies in Gradle (`gradle dependencies`). You can try to delete versions of eureka client and server, maby conflict in versions.

Answer (score 2):

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext

`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` contains `servlet-api` which may conflict with other components.

May exclude this can help (for maven):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>${springcloud.eureka.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```